# Windows 11 and Windows Hello for PIN signins

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, group-policy

I was testing something on my personal Win 11 desktop, trying to reproduce a problem a coworker was facing when trying to run some PowerShell scripts I wrote to help devs get new machines set up and configured for development usage. I added a work account which pulled in some various security policies onto my computer, but it wouldn't let me log on with that account, which is what I wanted to test. (To do that, I had to set up a fresh Win 10 install [thanks to a key from MSDN] and tell Windows from the start that it was for work usage, and then the first account I set up authenticated via Azure Active Directory.)

In any case, on the original Win 11 node, I removed the work account, but some of the policies appear to still remain. For example, I can't see Windows Hello settings anymore; I have a PIN configured, but I can't change it. It had forced me to change it from 4 digits to 8 digits after I added that work account. I've looked through the various local policies, but I'm not seeing anything configured that should cause problems. Anyone have any thoughts as to what I might be missing? I'd really like to change my 8 digit pin back to a 4 digit pin, considering that that machine is primarily my gaming rig and doesn't need stringent security measures applied to it.

I could wipe it and start fresh, but I'm really keen on doing that at all. But I do have 9 days of PTO coming up, so if I have to, I have to; but I'd really rather just figure out how to re-enable Windows Hello instead. I would have thought that simply removing the work account would remove the relevant policies, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Don't you have any of [these policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/hello-for-business/hello-manage-in-organization)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what triggered the change, but this ultimately resolved itself after some time. Maybe it was when newer Windows Updates were applied, but a few days after I removed the work account, I was able to see the Windows Hello settings again and reset the pin back to 4 digits.